# Why was my question marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, duplicate-questions

Yesterday I posted a question and it was marked as a duplicate.

[Isset()/Empty(), Arrays and Ternary Operator [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893441/isset-empty-arrays-and-ternary-operator)

The suggested topic [How can I create a new operator in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347694/how-can-i-create-a-new-operator-in-php) does not answer my questions in any way. There are some solutions suggested there but they do not work for arrays (and I specified in the header that I am talking about arrays).

So, is there any way to reopen my question?

Comment: To answer the question "So, is there any way to reopen my question?": Yes, post on meta. But be sure that your reason for reopening holds water.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree it is not a duplicate. Let me see whether I can reopen it in chat.

Comment: its now re-opened by  `PeeHaa 埽, NullPonyPointer, cryptic ツ, Daniel Fischer, Bill the Lizard♦`

Comment: All these people trying to look cool with their weird characters attached to their user names. Pathetic.

Comment: @PekkasupportsGoFundMonica, what on earth could it possibly make it matter enough to call someone else "pathetic"?

Comment: @tgm1024--Monicawasmistreated sporting one of those bad boys himself at the time... [assume good faith]